call register type before use user defined type (UDT)
I'm trying to run a function in a package, within a handle in my API and I'm getting an error
call register type before use user defined type (UDT)
I launched the function itself via a SQL query and it worked
it means there’s a mistake in the handle itself, SOS, I’ve been suffering for hours now
here is code
    var responsibleID string
    query := `
        BEGIN
            :1 := MYDB.RESPONSIBLE_BO.GetContractorIDByName(:2);
        END;
    `
    err = tx.QueryRow(query, sql.Out{Dest: &responsibleID}, req.ResponsibleName).Scan(&responsibleID)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Failed to get ResponsibleID:", err)
        tx.Rollback()
        ctx.SetStatus(apieasy.InternalServerError, "Failed to get ResponsibleID, error: %v", err)
        return
    }

and function itself if it necessary
  FUNCTION GetContractorIDByName (i_sNAME IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN CHAR
    IS 
      v_res CONTRACTOR.CONTRACTORID % TYPE;
    BEGIN 
      IF (i_sNAME IS NOT NULL)
      THEN
        BEGIN
          SELECT CONTRACTORID
            INTO v_res
            FROM CONTRACTOR
            WHERE NAME = i_sNAME;
          EXCEPTION
            WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
              CREATECONTRACTOR (i_sNAME, NULL, NULL, 'created by function GetContractorIDByName', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0);
              COMMIT;
              BEGIN
                  SELECT CONTRACTORID
                    INTO v_res
                    FROM CONTRACTOR
                    WHERE NAME = i_sNAME;
              EXCEPTION
                  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002, 'Failed to retrieve newly created contractor TRY AGAIN');
              END;
        END;
      ELSE 
                RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Undefined nom name');
      END IF;
      RETURN v_res;
    END GetContractorIDByName;


The tx.Rollback() is possibly pointless as you only appear to use SELECTs in the most common execution path so there will be nothing to rollback (but there could be something in the transaction prior to this statement that could be rolled back - hence only possibly pointless). However, when you hit the NO_DATA_FOUND exception then the rollback is definitely futile as the function COMMITs so anything prior to the function call cannot be rolled back. This definitely appears to be an error in the logic (but is independent of the question you are asking here).

@MT0 you right, i will fix this lol, but i beg smone help me solve my problem
